# Tkinter formatting on decimal

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, formatting, decimal

I am new to Python and stuck on how to fix this simple formatting problem.  In the example code I am trying to align the column on the decimal but not having any success. If the two numbers are the same length it works but if the numbers are a different length, it no longer formats. Also the Total does not align correctly. And pointers would be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
 
# set-up window
window = Tk()
window.geometry('300x300')
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.title('Example')
  
 
# calculate add or minus function
def calculate():
    char_ok = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.']
    Item1Amt = Item1.get()
    Item2Amt = Item2.get()
    
    if float(Item1Amt) in char_ok:
        return True

    if True:
        TotalAmt = float(Item1Amt) + float(Item2Amt)
        Item1.delete(0, END)
        Item1Amt_insert = "{:>15,.2f}".format(float(Item1Amt))
        Item1.insert(0, Item1Amt_insert)
        print ( Item1Amt_insert)
     
        Item2.delete(0, END)
        Item2Amt_insert = "{:>15,.2f}".format(float(Item2Amt))
        Item2.insert(0, Item2Amt_insert)
        print(Item2Amt_insert)

        TotalAmt_Disp = "{:>15,.2f}".format(float(TotalAmt))
        Totallabel1 = Label(window, text=TotalAmt_Disp, borderwidth=1, relief='solid', background='#D3D3D3', width=15)
        Totallabel1.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=W)
        print(TotalAmt_Disp)

def clear():
    Item1.delete(0, 'end')
    Item2.delete(0, 'end')

 
# labels
label_1 = Label(window, text='Item #1', padx = 30, pady=10)
label_1.grid(row=3, sticky=E)
 
label_2 = Label(window, text='Item #2', padx = 30, pady=10)
label_2.grid(row=4, sticky=E)
 
label_3 = Label(window, text='Total:', padx = 30, pady=10)
label_3.grid(row=5, sticky=E)
 
#Label_3Disp = Label(window, text='', borderwidth=1, relief='solid', background='#D3D3D3', width=20) 
#Label_3Disp.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=0, pady=15,   sticky='w') 
 
# button
calculate_btn = Button(window, text='Calculate', width=10,  command=calculate, padx=10, pady=10)
calculate_btn.grid(column=1, row=6, pady=20, sticky=W)
  
# text fields
Item1 = Entry(window)
Item1.grid(column=1, row=3)

Item2 = Entry(window)
Item2.grid(column=1, row=4)

#Total = Entry(window)
#Total.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=W)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use monospaced font, like `Courier New`, for the two entry widgets and the total label.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Entry` and `Label` widgets do not use monospaced font by default, so the width in pixels for different contents having same width in characters will not be the same.

Use monospaced font for the entry widgets and the total label instead:

```py
...
fnt = ('Courier New', 10)

def calculate():
    ...
        Totallabel1 = Label(window, text=TotalAmt_Disp, borderwidth=1, relief='solid',
                            background='#D3D3D3', width=15, font=fnt)
    ...

...
# text fields
Item1 = Entry(window, font=fnt)
Item1.grid(column=1, row=3)

Item2 = Entry(window, font=fnt)
Item2.grid(column=1, row=4)
...
```

And the result:

[image]

---

However, I would suggest:

- align the text in the entry widgets and the total label to the right
- create the total label once and update it inside `calculate()`

```py
...
fnt = ('Courier New', 10)

def calculate():
    try:
        Item1Amt = float(Item1.get())
        Item2Amt = float(Item2.get())
        TotalAmt = Item1Amt + Item2Amt

        Item1.delete(0, END)
        Item1.insert(0, f'{Item1Amt:.2f}')

        Item2.delete(0, END)
        Item2.insert(0, f'{Item2Amt:.2f}')

        Totallabel1['text'] = f'{TotalAmt:.2f}'
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

...

# text fields
Item1 = Entry(window, font=fnt, justify=RIGHT)
Item1.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=EW)

Item2 = Entry(window, font=fnt, justify=RIGHT)
Item2.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=EW)

Totallabel1 = Label(window, borderwidth=1, relief='solid',
                    background='#D3D3D3', font=fnt, anchor=E)
Totallabel1.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=EW)
...
```

Result:

[image]